# Problema em rodar aplicação web .net com oracle. Chave duplicada

Tags: c#, oracle, mvc

Boa tarde, implementei uma app Mvc que utilizo o acesso ao Oracle através do Oracle.ManagedDataAccess versao :4.122.19.1.  Porém recebia a seguinte mensagem do IIS ao rodar a app:

```
Erro de Configuração       Há uma seção 'oracle.manageddataaccess.client' duplicada definida
```

A origem do erro era a section que é adicionada ao web.config, quando se instala o oracle:

```
 <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

Ao fazer algumas pesquisas identifiquei que o erro ocorria devido a no web.config estar setada a versão 4.122.19.0 e no machine.config (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config) estar configurada uma versão diferente. Ao setar a versão do machine.config identica a da aplicação ela roda sem problema. Porém sempre que atuo com outro projeto, ocorre o mesmo erro, e é necessário sempre a alteração manual do arquivo machine.config.

Alguma sugestão de como resolver este problema, todos os frameworks foram reinstalados, o oracle está rodando perfeitamente na maquina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro tem relação com o Oracle Data Provider for .NET. Existe o driver gerenciado e o não gerenciado. Você está utilizando o driver Gerenciado, e como tem a necessidade de rodar várias aplicações com versões distintas, deve utilizar o driver não gerenciado.

Uma forma simples de verificar o driver é no próprio machine.config, onde o gerenciado aparece a section: oracle.dataaccess.client já no não gerenciado aparece: oracle.manageddataaccess.client.

Documentação onde encontrei a solução:https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm

Comment: Está correto, no computador de um desenvolvedor ao lado, que o projeto carrega e não precisa fazer edição no machine.config (comportamento que eu busco) no arquivo apresenta a <section name="oracle.dataaccess.client" ...>. Vou alterar as versões aqui, Obrigado.